# Conditional execution in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

How can I choose to execute a portion of the graph based on a condition?

I have a part of my network which is to be executed only if a placeholder value is provided in `feed_dict`. An alternate path is taken if the value is not provided. How do I go about implementing this using tensorflow?

Here are the relevant portions of my code:

```
sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={inputs: mnist.test.images, outputs: mnist.test.labels})

N = tf.shape(outputs)
    cost = 0
    if N > 0:
        y_N = tf.slice(h_c, [0, 0], N)
        cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_N, outputs, name='xentropy')
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='xentropy_mean')
```

In the above code, I'm looking for something to use in the place of `if N > 0:`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hrm.  It's possible that what you want is tf.control_flow_ops.cond()
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py#L597

But that's not exported into the tf namespace, and I'm answering without checking how guaranteed-stable this interface is, but it's used in released models, so go for it. :)

However:  Because you actually know in advance what path you want when you construct the feed_dict, you could also take a different approach of invoking a separate path through your model.  The standard way to do this is to, e.g., set up code like:

```
def model(input, n_greater_than):
  ... cleverness ...
  if n_greater_than:
     ... other cleverness...
  return tf.reduce_mean(input)


out1 = model(input, True)
out2 = model(input, False)
```

And then pull the out1 or out2 nodes depending upon what you know when you're about to run your computation and set the feed_dict.  Remember that by default, if the model references the same variables (create them *outside* the model() func), then you'll basically have two separate paths through.

You can see an example of this in the convolutional mnist example:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py#L165

I'm a fan of doing it this way without introducing control flow dependencies if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example, that can get you started. It executes different parts of the graph based on the shape of the tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable([[3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0]])
b = tf.Variable([[1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0]])
l = tf.shape(a)

add_op, sub_op = tf.add(a, b), tf.sub(a, b)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
t = sess.run(l)

print sess.run(sub_op if t[0] == 3 else add_op)

sess.close()
```

Change 3 to 2 to see how tensor will be subtracted. As you see I initiated the nodes for `add` and `sub` and `shape`, then in the graph I check for the shape and go run the specific part.